# MVC Routing Misunderstanding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, controller

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application. For some reason, everytime I think I understand routing, something pops up that I don't understand. Currently, I have two routes that I can't seem to figure out. My directory structure looks like the following

```
- Views
  - Internal
    - Profile
      - Index.cshtml
    - Input
      - Page1.cshtml
```

In my global.asax.cs file, I have added the following mappings:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
    "UserProfileInfo",
    "{controller}/profile",
    new { controller = "Internal", action = "UserProfileInfo" }
  );


  routes.MapRoute(
    "Page1",
    "{controller}/input/page1",
    new { controller = "Internal", action = "Page1" }
  );
```

In MyController, I have the following:

```
  public ActionResult UserProfileInfo()
  {
    return View("~/Views/internal/profile/Index.cshtml");
  }

  public ActionResult Page1()
  {
    return View("~/Views/internal/input/Page1.cshtml");
  }
```

I want to store my actions in a single controller. I thought I had everything setup properly. But I continue to get a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What URL's are giving you a 404?

Comment: When I punch in http://localhost:[port]/internal/input/page1 or http://localhost:[port]/profile/info I get a 404. I have noticed when I enter http://localhost:[port]/internal/UserProfileInfo my page comes up. But, that is not the url I want to use.

Comment: You may need to remove the existing default route, which may be matching first

Comment: What will the "existing default route" line look like?

Comment: The {controller}/{action}/{id} route that is added for you in the default global.asax.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "Controller" suffix from the controller name in your calls to MapRoute to create a mapping to a class called `InternalController`. The Controller suffix is appended by the framework when looking for a matching implementation. e.g.:

```
    routes.MapRoute( 
    "UserProfileInfo", 
    "{controller}/profile", 
    new { controller = "Internal", action = "UserProfileInfo" } 
);
```

Comment: well, they aren't there in my actual code. just in this post. I have updated the post. Thank you for pointing this out though.